# How to dynamically add rows and detect and delete clicked?

Tags: android, eclipse, rows, android-tablelayout

I'm dynamically adding rows to the table. I have few textViews[] that I add to the row[] and then I add row[] to the table. That's ok, but then I want to detect click on textView[] and delete that row, also I want the numbers of the textViews below deleted ones to decrease.

example:

```
1 a a a //(I delete this row)
2 b b b
3 c c c
```

after deleting, I want to have this:

```
1 b b b
2 c c c
```

I have tried adding onClickListener to one textView[], but sometimes it deletes row[] and decreases number, sometimes don't.

Can someone write me some example to try out?

**EDIT:** Here's my code (I think it's all that's needed for this)
This is the code on my button for adding rows:

```
public TextView textViewKoeficijent[] = new TextView[50];
public TextView textViewBr[] = new TextView[50];
public TextView textViewObrisi[] = new TextView[50];
public TextView textViewTip[] = new TextView[50];
public TextView textViewPar[] = new TextView[50];


   fkoeficijent = Double.valueOf(koeficijent);
        koefIzracun = koefIzracun * fkoeficijent;

        TextView textViewKoeficijentIzracun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUkupniKoeficijentIzracun);
        koefIzracun = Math.round(koefIzracun*100)/100.0d;
        koefIzracunString = String.valueOf(koefIzracun);
        textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText(koefIzracunString);

        final TableLayout PopisParova = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);

        final TableRow noviPar[] = new TableRow[50];

        LayoutParams paramsBroj = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        paramsBroj.setMargins(4, 0, 2, 4);
        LayoutParams paramsPar = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
        paramsPar.setMargins(2, 0, 2, 4);
        LayoutParams paramsKoef = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
        paramsKoef.setMargins(2, 0, 4, 4);

        //onclicklistener:
        OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                id = view.getId();

                brpara --;

                TextView textViewKoeficijentIzracun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUkupniKoeficijentIzracun);
                if(brpara==1){
                    textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText("0");
                    koefIzracun = 1;
                }

                else{
                koeficijent = textViewKoeficijent[id].getText().toString();
                fkoeficijent = Double.valueOf(koeficijent);
                koefIzracun = koefIzracun / fkoeficijent;

                koefIzracun = Math.round(koefIzracun*100)/100.0d;
                koefIzracunString = String.valueOf(koefIzracun);
                textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText(koefIzracunString);}

                PopisParova.removeViewAt(id);
                //PopisParova.removeView(noviPar[id]);

                for(i=1; i<=brpara; i++){
                    if(i>id){
                        String bri = String.valueOf(i-1);
                        textViewBr[i].setText(bri);
                        textViewObrisi[i].setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(i-1);
                    }
                }

            }};

         {
            textViewBr[brpara] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViewBr[brpara].setLayoutParams(paramsBroj);
            textViewBr[brpara].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textViewBr[brpara].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            brojPara = String.valueOf(brpara);
            textViewBr[brpara].setText(brojPara); 
            textViewBr[brpara].setId(brpara);
            }

         {
            textViewPar[brpara] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViewPar[brpara].setLayoutParams(paramsPar);
            textViewPar[brpara].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textViewPar[brpara].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            textViewPar[brpara].setText(par);    
            textViewPar[brpara].setId(brpara);
            }

         {
            textViewTip[brpara] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViewTip[brpara].setLayoutParams(paramsPar);
            textViewTip[brpara].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textViewTip[brpara].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            textViewTip[brpara].setText(tip);    
            textViewTip[brpara].setId(brpara);
            }

         {
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara].setLayoutParams(paramsPar);
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara].setText(koeficijent);    
            textViewKoeficijent[brpara].setId(brpara);
            }

         {
            textViewObrisi[brpara] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setLayoutParams(paramsKoef);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setText("X");    
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setId(brpara);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setClickable(true);
            textViewObrisi[brpara].setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            }

        noviPar[brpara] = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        noviPar[brpara].addView(textViewBr[brpara]);
        noviPar[brpara].addView(textViewPar[brpara]);
        noviPar[brpara].addView(textViewTip[brpara]);
        noviPar[brpara].addView(textViewKoeficijent[brpara]);
        noviPar[brpara].addView(textViewObrisi[brpara]);
        PopisParova.addView(noviPar[brpara]);

        brpara++;

        editTextPar.setText("");
        editTextTip.setText("");
        editTextKoeficijent.setText("");
```

**EDIT [2]:**
brpara is my counter so I know which is number of row which is being added. I have a max of 20 rows.
Also, my loop is working perfectly for deleting one row, but when I delete multiple rows at once, it only changes my row numbers for the first time and after that only deletes rows.

Comment: If you have multiple rows, perhaps a `ListView` with a custom adapter will make more sense.

Comment: Your question states that sometimes what are you want to do is done and sometimes not. This tell me that there is something wrong in your code, so let me check your code. Oh wait... You have not post any...

Comment: added my code so you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution is to replace deleted rows, and their data, with rows following, and their data and delete last row. So it looks like the deleted row is really deleted.

```
row[x] = row[x+1] // want to delete this
row[x+1] = row[x+2]
//... and like that until the last row
row[last] // delete this row
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing is this:

Let's say that brpara = 3.

You click the view with id = 2.

You execute brbara --; So brbara is now 2.

You check if id != brpara they are NOT so no renumbering. Logical Problem!

Furthermore you have this loop:

```
for(i=id+1; i<=brpara; i++){
                    i=id+1;
                    String bri = String.valueOf(id);
                    textViewBr[i].setText(bri);
                    textViewObrisi[i].setId(id);}
```

You say that i must be id+1 (in our example 3) to < brpara (in our example 2) so 3 <= 2 it never executes, if however id and brpara allows loop execution you resetting the i inside the loop

```
i=id+1;
```

If for example the loop starting with i = id+1 let's say id=2 so it is now 3 and go inside the loop the i will be always 3 because you are resetting it inside the loop.

It is not clear from your code how are you using brpara but the loop for renumbering is wrong. So let's assume that brpara is ALWAYS the last index in the array then I suggest the following code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            id = view.getId();

            TextView textViewKoeficijentIzracun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUkupniKoeficijentIzracun);
            if(brpara==1){
                textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText("0");
                koefIzracun = 1;
            }

            else{
            koeficijent = textViewKoeficijent[id].getText().toString();
            fkoeficijent = Double.valueOf(koeficijent);
            koefIzracun = koefIzracun / fkoeficijent;

            koefIzracun = Math.round(koefIzracun*100)/100.0d;
            koefIzracunString = String.valueOf(koefIzracun);
            textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText(koefIzracunString);}

            //FIRST RENUMBER ALL VIEWS FROM id+1 to brpara               
            if(id!=brpara){
                for(i=id+1; i<=brpara; i++){
                    String bri = String.valueOf(i - 1); //<--HERE MAYBE MUST BE i-1 NOT id...
                    textViewBr[i].setText(bri);
                    textViewObrisi[i].setId(id);} //THIS DOESN'T FEEL RIGHT MAYBE i INSTEAD OF id? OR i - 1?
            }

            //AND FINALY REMOVE VIEW AND DECREASE brpara...
            PopisParova.removeViewAt(id);
            brpara --; 
        }
```

My suggestion assumes that brpara is always the last index and you are renumbering from the clicked view + 1 to the end. However there is a more elegant solution which is to create a function that renumbers the whole array from top to bottom regardless the view clicked and call it whenever a view gets added or removed. That way you will not have to manage brpara at all but this depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

**Based on your Edits**

Try this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            id = view.getId();

            TextView textViewKoeficijentIzracun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUkupniKoeficijentIzracun);
            if((brpara - 1)==1){
                textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText("0");
                koefIzracun = 1;
            } else {
                koeficijent = textViewKoeficijent[id].getText().toString();
                fkoeficijent = Double.valueOf(koeficijent);
                koefIzracun = koefIzracun / fkoeficijent;

                koefIzracun = Math.round(koefIzracun*100)/100.0d;
                koefIzracunString = String.valueOf(koefIzracun);
                textViewKoeficijentIzracun.setText(koefIzracunString);

                PopisParova.removeViewAt(id);
                brpara --;

                for(i=1; i<=brpara; i++){
                    String bri = String.valueOf(i);
                    textViewBr[i].setText(bri);
                    textViewObrisi[i].setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(i);
                }

            }
        }
```

Since brpara is a counter you should decrease it only when you are actually remove the view. You may have to change the

```
if((brpara - 1)==1){
```

with

```
if(brpara==1){
```

based on your needs. But now the loop seems to be OK.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have updated my loop and added some explanations you needed, so please check it now

Comment: don't know why, but neither all my tries or your suggestions didn't work.. but I come to the solution, similar to your renumbering all suggestion.. I'm doing DeletedRow=DeletedRow+1; DeletedRow+1=DeletedRow+2; and so on and then delete the last row, so it is good now